# Show the value of the property and not just the type

Tags: visual-studio-code

In our dear VS Code when we hover in any variable the vscode by default shows the type of this variable, when it is an object, it shows the structure of the object.

e.g:

[image: object hover]

I would like to know if in addition to showing the type or structure it is possible to show the value of the properties.

If this is not possible in the vscode itself, is there any extension that does something like this?

Comment: You have written `${THEME.colors.highlight}`. The attribute you are targeting isn't a constant, therefore it is mutable and may change at any time. VSCode has no easy way of finding out what the variable will hold at the current line.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get to what you want (show variables value), is to add the variable in the debug window to the watch list. In debug mode, when you hit a breakpoint, your watch will evaluate the value at the current time (whether its been set, or not etc.) and will output what it is in that window for you.
See below:

[image: Visual Studio Code - Watch List]

[image: Visual Studio Code - Watch List 2]